# GROUPING A TABLE BASED ON MULTIPLE FIELDS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with following format[image]

Now i am using Access and want to create a table which will provide me sum of units where Segment is commercial, at the same time I just want to sum Subregions where they are same..means MCA+MCA+MCA... Also the period should be same where we have added them..means 2013Q1 should be added too 2013Q1 only and grouped in that format.

Something like below

[image]

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

The following query totals the unit while grouping on the other fields.  To change the range that it totals over, you will either be adding a `WHERE` clause or you will change the fields that it is `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT [Sub Region], [Corporate Family], [HP Segment], [Product Category], [Period], Sum([Units])
FROM TableName
GROUP BY [Sub Region], [Corporate Family], [HP Segment], [Product Category], [Period]
```